# SQL query is not executed in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-ce, left-join

I use simple `.sdf` as database and using SQL Server CE `SqlCeConnection` to connect to it.

```
con.Open()
dataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter()
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT DISTINCT cr.category_name, SUM(ex.amount) FROM category_report cr LEFT JOIN expenditure ex ON ex.category_name = cr.category_name GROUP BY cr.category_name", con)
ds = New DataSet
dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
con.close()
```

I use the above code to populate the gridview, but query is not executed since `SUM(ex.amount)` is there... Please help me..

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: no error message... it will stop executing

Comment: i have checked it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), the query is correct...

Comment: What do you mean `it will stop executing`? Have you tried to follow the code with a debugger?

Comment: yeah i do.... in VS2012 , but the execution stop and no error is displaying... so I guess the problem is with the query...but query is also correct when i cross checked....